# My UV map has too many pieces

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I hit UV unwrap and my model has split into a lot more pieces than I marked out with seams and I don't know why. Can anyone help me? I am sure it is simple.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What option did you select for unwrapping? Smart UV project?

Comment: yes I used smart UV project it seems to have blown apart all over the place

Comment: also if you look at the map one of the verticies at the bottom left (the t shirt map) is heading off the page on its own. I put the file on the blend exchange here

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2376" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2376/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use seams, don't use "Smart UV Project" but "Unwrap". Smart UV project has the potential to split up into even more pieces than your seams showed based on geometry (the angle between faces), but "Unwrap" will simply use your seams. As far as the one vertex by itself, it was most likely not selected before the unwrap. Use <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then do an Unwrap.

[image]

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it looks like you already found out :-)